# how to configure a vps server to send emails on linux

Tags: linux, email, smtp, sendmail, vps

I am planning to rent a vps outside my primary site

I want to configure this vps to send emails only not receive.

say at my primary site I have an smtp server smtp.xyz.com

I don't want to use this smtp server for the new vps

how can I configure sendmail/postfix to send emails from this vps?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your Linux distribution.

On Debian you can easily configure your mail server as satellite server. This means that the server can send mails but can not receive them. Normally you need an relay host. See here for an example: http://kurinchilamp.kurinchilion.com/2009/08/ubuntu-postfix-sendmail.html

If you want to configure Postfix directly you have to specify the relay options. See here for a description: http://www.postfix.org/SMTPD_ACCESS_README.html

The idea is that you relay only for localhost. See the null client configuration: http://www.postfix.org/STANDARD_CONFIGURATION_README.html#null_client